# Can I let a superclass return reference to the "actual type"?

Tags: python, inheritance

Well as title: Can I let a superclass return reference to the "actual type"?

Basically I have an **immutable** class, which is a subtype of "float". This class if further subtyped to make difference between the several different angles.

Now the methods for all those sub-types is the same for most part. However if I do a function on the class it's type should be retained. (But I can't modify the value so I need to return a copy). The code:

```
class Anomaly(float):
    """
    Anomaly class
    """
    def __new__(cls, val):
        return super().__new__(cls, val)

    def ModulateFullCircle(self):
        """
        Modulates value to [0, 2*pi) interval
        :return: Modulated anomaly
        """
        p = self % (2*pi)
        if p < 0:
            p += 2*pi
        return Anomaly(p)

    def ModulateBidirectional(self):
        """
        Modulates value to (-pi, pi] interval
        :return: Modulated anomaly
        """
        p = self % (2*pi)
        if p > pi:
            p -= 2*pi
        return Anomaly(p)


class TrueAnomaly(Anomaly):
    """
    True Anomaly class
    """

    def __new__(cls, val):
        super().__new__(cls, val)

a = TrueAnomaly(8.2*pi)
b = a.ModulateBidirectional()
#now b should still be of type "TrueAnomaly"
```

Now a solution is simple copy-pasting the functions to each subclass, but can I do this in a better way? That doesn't copy the same function multiple times?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`self` in your methods has the type you need, so you can just use it. Instead of

```
return Anomaly(p)
```

write

```
return type(self)(p)
```

Alternatively, you could define an initializing classmethod in `Anomaly` as

```
@classmethod
def from_float(cls, p):
    return cls(p)
```

and use it as

```
return self.from_float(p)
```

This may be useful if you need some non-trivial constructors.

By the way,

1. your `__new__` implementations do not seem to serve any purpose
2. in `ModulateFullCircle`, `p` is guaranteed to be positive after `% (2 * pi)`.

Comment: ... since in Python the result of the modulus operation has the sign of the right operand.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams it still takes the modulo operator right, and not mirror it around 0 (absolute value)?